# Aggregating nodes based on substring

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to collate nodes based on the substring match . Below is the XML that I am manipulating :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CurrencyPairs xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <ActiveCurrenciesNumber>5</ActiveCurrenciesNumber>
    <CurrencyPair>AEDAFN</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>AEDCHE</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>AEDEUR</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>AEDUSD</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>AFNAED</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>AFNCHE</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>AFNEUR</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>AFNUSD</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>CHEAED</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>CHEAFN</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>CHEEUR</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>CHEUSD</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>EURAED</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>EURAFN</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>EURCHE</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>EURUSD</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>USDAED</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>USDAFN</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>USDCHE</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>USDEUR</CurrencyPair>
    <PairsNumber>20</PairsNumber>
</CurrencyPairs>
```

I have tried multiple things but I am unable to get the desired output based on the substring match.
The desired output should be as below :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CurrencyPairs xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <ActiveCurrenciesNumber>5</ActiveCurrenciesNumber>
    <CurrencyPair>AEDAFN,AEDCHE,AEDEUR,AEDUSD</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>AFNAED,AFNCHE,AFNEUR,AFNUSD</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>CHEAED,CHEAFN,CHEEUR,CHEUSD</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>EURAED,EURAFN,EURCHE,EURUSD</CurrencyPair>
    <CurrencyPair>USDAED,USDAFN,USDCHE,USDEUR</CurrencyPair>
    </CurrencyPairs>
```

I have tried multiple methods using Grouping etc. but all the efforts went in vain. It will be great if someone can share an example of such scenario.
Can anyone please assist in getting the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what exactly have you tried - seems pretty straightforward, even trivial:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/CurrencyPairs">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ActiveCurrenciesNumber"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="CurrencyPair" group-by="substring(., 1, 3)">
            <CurrencyPair> 
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()" separator=","/>
            </CurrencyPair>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```